# Close two open forms together in a Winforms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a Windows forms application

In the parent form I open two forms together - `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest` and `FrmReleasedInPodium`

In parent form I opened two forms like this:

```
frm1 = New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
frm1.Location = New Point(375, 0)
frm1.MdiParent = Me
frm1.Show()

frm6 = New FrmReleasedInPodium
frm6.Location = New Point(809, 0)
frm6.MdiParent = Me
frm6.Show()
```

in `FrmReleasedInPodium` I have a close button.

When clicking the close button I have to close both forms, so I wrote this code:

```
  Me.Close()
  Dim form2 = New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest()
  form2.Close()
```

but this is not closing my `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest`,only closing `FrmReleasedInPodium`.

When clicking the close button I have to close both forms.. how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest` and then immediately closing it. That new instance has nothing to do with the original instance you created in your first form.

To close both, you're going to have to pass a reference to the original `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest` into your instance of `FrmReleasedInPodium`.

---

Pass the instance of `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest` into `FrmReleasedInPodium`:

```
frm6 = New FrmReleasedInPodium(frm1)
frm6.Location = New Point(809, 0)
frm6.MdiParent = Me
frm6.Show()
```

Then reference it in `FrmReleasedInPodium`:

```
Public Class FrmReleasedInPodium

    private frmRDR as FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest

    Public Sub New(ByVal frmRDR As FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest)
        InitializeComponent
        Me.frmRDR = frmRDR
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: sir then why you are passing frm1

Comment: sir see your code..you named it somthing like:frmRDR  right

Comment: i am getting error while passing frm1 in :frm6 = New FrmReleasedInPodium(frm1)

Comment: in close button i added code like this:me.close() frmRDR.Close() but getting error while reaching frmRDR.Close()

Comment: yes i am placing the code FrmReleasedInPodium error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.